# ASP.NET migrations is creating duplicate bridge entities

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am designing a web application with ASP.NET using MVC 5 and EF 6.  Our team uses code first migrations to design our database.  In our project we have two models - `Location` and `Recreation`.  Recreation is essentially an enumerable tag that can be applied to any Location (many-to-many relationship), so I designed a 3rd bridge entity model to handle the relations (so I can reference it in the code).  Here are the abbreviated model definitions:

**Location:**

```cs
/*
 * Represents a location on a map.
 */
public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public String Label { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Recreation> Recreations { get; set; }
}
```

**Recreation:**

```cs
/*
 * Represents a recreation activity type, such as Hiking or Camping, that 
 * can be applied to any location as a tag (each Location may have 0 or more
 * Recreation tags).
 */
public class Recreation
{
    public int RecreationID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

**Bridge Entity:**

```cs
/*
 * Bridge entity to handle associations of Location and Recreation
 */
public class LocationRecreation
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Location")]
    [Column(Order = 1)] 
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public int LocationID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Recreation")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Recreation")]
    public int RecreationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Recreation Recreation { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a migration and run `update-database`, this works with the default scaffolding of controllers/views.  But, upon looking in the Server Explorer tab, I see the following tables:

- `Locations`
- `Recreations`
- `LocationRecreations`
- `RecreationLocations`  *(extra table?)*

The views process CRUD on `LocationRecreations`, but the virtual properties point to `RecreationLocations`, so they don't work as that table remains empty.

> What is causing the migrations to create a duplicate table?  Can I modify my models in some way to allow for only one table to be created, and so that the virtual properties function as intended?

**EDIT:**

I have re-created the error in a new Visual Studio Project hosted [here on Github](https://github.com/aaroncarsonart/BridgeEntityExample).  For clarity, I selected Individual User accounts, and thus am using the single `ApplicationDbContext` in the `IdentityModels.cs` file for my db context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recreation> Recreations { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


    // Associate a Location with a Recreation.
    public void AddOrUpdateRecreationLocation(string locationLabel, string recreationLabel)
    {
        var location = this.Locations.SingleOrDefault(l => l.Label == locationLabel);
        var recreation = location.Recreations.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Label == recreationLabel);

        //i if it does not exist, register the item.
        if (recreation == null) location.Recreations.Add(this.Recreations.Single(r => r.Label == recreationLabel));
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your model classes and got only the 3 required tables, not the extra one. The only thing I did differently was not use update-database, I just created a controller & view and ran the app. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I think the problem is I needed to have the entity framework build the bridge table for me, and access it only using virtual properties in the `Recreation` and `Location` classes.  I removed the `LocationRecreation` class and table, and now things work ok, except i can't access the table directly from a `DbContext` class.  I will leave this question up in case others have more insights on the topic.

Comment: I don't think you gave the complete setup and steps to reproduce. Can you reproduce this problem starting from an empty project, with no pre-existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue.   `Location` and `Relation` both need a `virtual ICollection<LocationRelation>` (a collection of my bridge entity).  The problem was I was telling the entity framework to point indirectly to the related items, and thus it inferred to create a third bridge table for me.

The `LocationRecreation` and `DbContext` code is fine.  Here are the modified `Location` and `Recreation` models:

```
/*
 * Represents a location on a map.
 */
public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public String Label { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection< LocationRecreation > LocRecs { get; set; }
}

/*
 * Represents a recreation activity type, such as Hiking or Camping, that 
 * can be applied to any location as a tag (each Location may have 0 or more
 * Recreation tags).
 */
public class Recreation
{
    public int RecreationID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection< LocationRecreation > LocationRecs { get; set; }
}
```